# Dynamic SAS macro variable

Tags: sas

I have a SAS code like this:

```
%if &tp. = kdb %then %do;
    %let sn = "&kdbsn.";
%end;
%if &tp. = bkb %then %do;
    %let sn = &bkbsn.;
%end;
%if &tp. = edw %then %do;
    %let sn = &edwsn.;
%end;
%if &tp. = odw %then %do;
    %let sn = &odwsn.;
%end;
%if &tp. = adw %then %do;
    %let sn = &adwsn.;
%end;

%put &sn;
```

I need to do this for many other cases and the pattern is always the same. Depending on the variable `&tp.` I set the variable `&sn.` to the same value as a variable with a name that has the first 3 characters equal to value of `&tp.` and two additional characters `sn`. Is there a function that would return the name of variable that I need so I don't need to have endless number of `if` statements?

Comment: Why does one add quotes and the other's don't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add more `&`.  The macro processor resolves `&&` to `&` and sets a note to itself to rescan the token for more macro processing.

```
%let tp=kdb;
%let kdbsn=1234;
%let sn=&&&tp.sn ;
```

So `&&` -> `&` and `&tp.` -> `kdb` to get `&kdbsn`, which will resolve to `1234`.